# Are $x$ and $y$ divisible by $n$, if so how do I prove it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $y$, $x$,are natural numbers, and $n$ is a prime number, $y = x + n$, $y>x>n$, and $y$ and $x$ are not coprime, is it true that $n$ is a divisor of both $x$ and $y$? If so could you please start off the proof and point me in the general direction of how to prove it, please don't show me the full proof, I want to solve it myself.

Comment: Hint: $6=2+4$  .

Comment: @Uncountable I know that, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: The reason I said it is because I think this suffices as a counterexample. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you know that how can you still ask whether $4\mid 6$ and $4\mid 2$ are true?

Comment: Oh dang, I forgot a specification.

Comment: @Uncountable there you go.

Comment: How about $10=6+4$ in this case?

Comment: @Uncountable any more?

Answer (score 3):

You can even say that any divisor of both $x$ and $y$ is also a divisor of $n$, hence $\gcd(x,y)=p$.

If $x$ and $y$ are coprime this is not necessarily true. Counter-example: twin primes differ by $2$, a prime number.

Comment: God, so many counter-examples, so many specifications needed to avoid them.

Comment: Oh! The post was modified when I was writing my answer, and I didn't check before posting. See my updated answer.

Comment: I don't know why my answer was downvoted: it corresponded to the first state of the O.P.'s question and was perfectly correct. I have modified it since then.

Comment: I don't feel like make more specifications in my question, so if x, and y are composite, is it correct, if so how would I prove that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what are the specifications finally: $x$ and $y$ are composite and not coprime?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: Well, you already have the answer: $p=\gcd(x,y)$.